# woocommerce how to show min/max price of each category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

When calling the [product_categories] shortcode, I'd like to show in the category title the minimum price of the products belonging to each listed category.

I can

1. customise the function woocommerce_template_loop_category_title() and insert a small db query like

```
$sql = 'SELECT min(min_price)
    FROM `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup`
    WHERE product_id IN (
        SELECT object_id
        FROM wp_term_relationships
        WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '.$category->term_id.')';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
if (!$results) {
    ... mmhh ...
} else {
    ..display the result
}
```

or

2. use a specific wc function or filter (not in my knowledge) and solve it in the wp/wc way

I was wandering not only to know a implementation of 2) but also to have an assessment about which one is the more efficient in terms of server execution time and resources.

thanks in advance